# Property file not updating

Tags: java, properties, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream, properties-file

EDIT

To give you guys the problem that I'm trying to solve -

I have a java ee dynamic web application and I'm using servlet 3.0. I need to store some data in a file that is internal to the project (like a properties file).
However, I need the data in this file to persist across deployments/reloads of the servlet context.

Here is the approach that I've taken to do that -

```
public void changeProperty(String file_name, String property, String value) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file_name);
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.load(in);
    in.close();

    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file_name);
    props.setProperty(property, value);
    props.store(out, null);
    out.close();
}
```

Is this the correct way to do this?
If not, how else can I do this?

Note - Using database calls is not an option and the data absolutely must persist across redeployments/reloads

Comment: Hint: read about java coding guidelines. No "_ "please.

Comment: @sidgate Per the Javadoc, flush is done by `Properties#store()`.

Comment: @SagarGalande _"But it is not getting updated until I open the file"_ -- what do you mean by this?

Comment: What do you mean "not getting updated until I open the file"? How do you know it is not updated without opening the file? What are you using to open it? And what's the connection between opening the file and context getting re-initialized?

Comment: @JimGarrison, It reflects changes only and only if I open the properties file which I am trying to update.

Comment: when you say "project context" do you mean it's an IDE project file? maybe the IDE isn't noticing the change until you open it. meaning, it's not a problem with Java, but just the way your IDE works

Comment: @RealSkeptic, I am new to java. I have no idea why it is re-initialized when I open file, but I am pretty sure that it re-initializes the context whenever I open the properties file.

Comment: what is re-initialized? we have very little to go on. the creation of the file looks correct though

Comment: We don't know what you mean by the terms "open the file", "project context", and "re-initialized".  You need to explain clearly what each of these means _to you_.

Comment: Context is a environment of a project where it resides and Initializes required things to run project.

Comment: And you don't explain in comments; you update the question instead. Nobody wants to read through 15 comments to get all the pieces required to maybe answer the question.

Comment: "Open the file"- opening actual properties file to see it.

Comment: Maybe your problem is that your IDE doesn't automatically "refresh" files? Meaning: some part of your project changes, and the IDE won't notice until you (for example) open the changed file?!

Comment: Thank you guys for your help. But can suggest me any alternative solution that would work for me

Comment: No, we can't because we still don't understand your problem!

Comment: you really need to be much more specific. we cant tell if this is an IDE properties file, a web server properties file, a stand alone app you have built which loads the file. something else all together. "the environment of the project" means very little. "opening the file" could mean "opening it in my IDE" or opening it with vim.

Comment: Opening file in IDE only to see if has updated the content.

Comment: why SHOULD the app update it right away? what code loads the file, and when it is called (did you write a method to load it, or is it part of some other framework)

Comment: I am trying to update some frequently changing data like user count, So for me it needs to be changed right away as new user registered. Whenever a chat room with the user created the property file needs to be updated, I have written a method to load it. The file is there in my project

Comment: The reference to the file in your running code will only be updated when it is read. It does not update automatically. If you want to update automatically on any changes, you may want to look at this doc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html